# Get Changeset Id(s) from Merge

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

In TFVC you can merge changesets from Branch A into Branch B. Is it possible to view which changesets - specifically which ids - from Branch A were merged into Branch B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `tf.exe` command line tool, the [merges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merges-command?view=azure-devops) command can provide the merge history between two branches.

So, in my example, from the source control root folder on my local machine I can run the following command in the shell of my choice `tf vc merges a b /recursive` to get a list of which changesets from `a` were included in merges to `b`:

```
Changeset Merged in Changeset Author                           Date
--------- ------------------- -------------------------------- ----------
   20096                20292 Joey Bloggs                      30/04/2018
   20102                20292 Joey Bloggs                      30/04/2018
   20103                20292 Joey Bloggs                      30/04/2018
```

Where the first column contains the changeset from branch `a` and the second column the changeset that merged it into branch `b`.

In order to get this working I had to add the folder location of `tf.exe` to my `PATH` variable.

Comment: While tf.exe is nice and clean solution. its still required visual studio installed. that's why i rather work with TFS API.

Comment: You can download tf.exe separately from Visual Studio here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/

Comment: Still, this required installation,this is just me. if you find this way easier and cleaner.use it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script :

```
$tfsUrl = "http://{Server}:{Port}/{Organization}/{Collection}"
$destinationBranchPath = "$/..."
$sourceBranchPath = "$/..."

# Change top with count of changesets you want to check
$body = 'repositoryId=&searchCriteria={"itemPath":"'+ $destinationBranchPath+'","itemVersion":"T","top":50}'
#Get top X changesets under destinationBranchPath
$changeSets  = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method post   "$tfsUrl/{Project}/_api/_versioncontrol/history?__v=5" -Body $body -UseDefaultCredentials).results 

#Run over all changesets and check if sourceBranchPath is part of merage soruce path 
foreach($changeSet in $changeSets)
{
   $IsMerged = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get  "$tfsUrl/_apis/tfvc/changesets/$($changeSet.changeList.changesetId)/changes" -UseDefaultCredentials).value.mergeSources.serverItem -like "*$sourceBranchPath*"
   if($IsMerged)
   {
        #Print results 
        Write-Output $changeSet.changeList
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. Do you run this from a PowerShell window or do I need to use the TFS shell?

Comment: I rather use poweshell shell.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another solution for anyone that don't want to use commands, but it will be a bit more time consuming if you want to know more than one merge

On TFS history of the merged branch, you can right click a changeset and choose Track Changeset option and then select the origin branch + merged branch in the next screen

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/view-where-when-changesets-have-been-merged?view=azure-devops